# TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object although datetime field not used Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I'm trying to migrate my datas, but django returns me `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object` error, although I just tried using datetime once, then deleted it, but still it returns an error. Here are my codes:

`models.py`

```
class Applicant(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    surname = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=40)
    motivation_letter = models.TextField(max_length=200)
    is_accepted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    photo = models.FileField(upload_to='static/applicant_photos')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

an error:

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, ccapp, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  Applying ccapp.0003_applicant_birth_date...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 234, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 245, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 112, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 327, in add_field
    self._remake_table(model, create_field=field)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/schema.py", line 188, in _remake_table
    self.effective_default(create_field)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 233, in effective_default
    return field.get_db_prep_save(self._effective_default(field), self.connection)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 789, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1431, in get_db_prep_value
    value = self.get_prep_value(value)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1410, in get_prep_value
    value = super().get_prep_value(value)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1270, in get_prep_value
    return self.to_python(value)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1371, in to_python
    parsed = parse_datetime(value)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/dateparse.py", line 106, in parse_datetime
    match = datetime_re.match(value)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Comment: can u show me ur migration file

Comment: @DEEPAKKUMAR

```# Generated by Django 2.2.6 on 2019-12-07 12:59

from django.db import migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('ccapp', '0005_auto_20191207_1257'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RemoveField(
            model_name='applicant',
            name='birth_date',
        ),
    ]

```

Comment: please show me code inside ccapp.0003_applicant_birth_date  migration  file

Comment: after this file  how many migration file are??

Comment: just go to your migrations folder, delete the migration file where you migrated dateTime and re-migrate the new model.

Comment: here is my ccapp.0003 migration file and I think error returns because of this line: ```field=models.DateTimeField(default=1),```


```# Generated by Django 2.2.6 on 2019-12-07 12:54

from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('ccapp', '0002_applicant'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='applicant',
            name='birth_date',
            field=models.DateTimeField(default='some string'),
            preserve_default=False,
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: pls delete this one and then re migrations and migrate

Comment: actually you passed  default='some string' in DateTimeField. that was the reason of error ...